# Como comparar elementos HTML por z-index real?

Tags: css, html, z-index

Dados dois elementos HTML arbitrários A e B na mesma página, como posso descobrir qual deles está "mais próximo" do usuário (i.e. se eles se sobrepusessem, qual deles obscureceria o outro)?

A [especificação CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers) do W3C descreve "contextos de empilhamento" (*stacking contexts*), que as *engines* de renderização que seguem os padrões devem implementar. Entretanto, não consegui encontrar um meio de acessar essa informação via JavaScript. Tudo a que tenho acesso é a propriedade css `z-index`, que por si só não diz muito, uma vez que na maior parte dos casos está como `auto` e - mesmo quando expressa por um número - não é um indicador confiável de como os elementos estão realmente exibidos (pois se eles pertencem a contextos de empilhamento diferentes, comparar z-índices é irrelevante).

Observação: eu estou interessado em elementos **arbitrários**; se ambos estão sob o ponteiro do mouse, apenas um será considerado *"hovered"*, de modo que determinar o mais próximo é trivial. Da mesma forma, se eu souber que eles se intersectam num ponto específico, posso usar [`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) tal como sugerido [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190361/520779) no SO em inglês. Entretanto, pode não ser o caso de eu conhecer um ponto assim, ou mesmo dele existir - os elementos podem não ter interseção um com outro.

Existe alguma solução geral para esse problema, de preferência uma que não envolva reimplementar o algoritmo de empilhamento que a *engine* de renderização já está fazendo de qualquer forma?

---

**Motivação:** existe uma limitação na fucionalidade "arrastar-e-soltar" (*drag-and-drop*) do jQuery, onde não é possível decidir com certeza onde soltar um elemento arrastado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versões antigas do jQuery escolheriam um deles meio que ao acaso, enquanto versões recentes realizam o *drop* em **ambos** (mais detalhes nessa [tentativa fracassada de resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12191247/520779)). O ideal seria escolher apenas um deles - o que está "mais próximo da tela"* - e fazer o *drop* só nele, e para isso eu preciso de um meio correto de determinar seu z-index real (ainda que isso envolva "re-inventar a roda", desde que o resultado seja [consistente](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/9VgvR/) com o empilhamento realizado pelo *browser*).

*Outra opção, como apontado por @utluiz, seria levar a **área de interseção** em consideração ao determinar o alvo correto - seja exigindo que o *helper* esteja totalmente contido no alvo, seja escolhendo o alvo com maior área de interseção (por exemplo, se está visualmente claro qual é o alvo correto, mas uma "pontinha" do *helper* toca um elemento distinto). Mas infelizmente, mesmo para calcular corretamente essa área de interseção é necessário se conhecer os índices z relativos, pois ela muda se um obscurece o outro.

---

**Atualização:** uma solução aparentemente basante completa foi [postada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35725621/520779), o [código completo está no GitHub](https://github.com/Jip-Hop/visuallyOnTop/) e há um [exemplo de uso no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt59sLcp/). À primeira vista parece ok, mas qualquer feedback adicional seria muito bem-vindo. Se tudo estiver correto, posto depois aqui como resposta.

Comment: Já me perguntei isso diversas vezes e nunca achei uma solução que não envolvesse reimplementar o algoritmo descrito na especificação do CSS - o que seria bastante pesado.

Comment: Não sei se vai adiantar alguma coisa, mas tenta pegar o `z-index` com `window.getComputedStyle( elemento ).getPropertyValue("z-index")`

Answer (score 6):

Considerando somente elementos que tenham z-índices explicitamente definidos, é possível simplificar bastante [o algoritmo da especificação do CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). Basicamente, ao comparar dois elementos, é necessário localizar o primeiro contexto de empilhamento que eles compartilham, e comparar os z-índices dos elementos que criaram esse contexto.

Dadas as funções `css` (que retorna o valor computado de uma propriedade), `contexto` (que retorna o contexto de empilhamento do elemento) e `descendente` (que detecta se o primeiro elemento passado descende do segundo), o algoritmo seria:

```
function naFrente(a, b, memo) {
    // Guardando o elemento passado na chamada original,
    // em caso de recursão
    memo = memo || [[],[]];
    memo[0].push(a);
    memo[1].push(b);

    // Contextos de empilhamento dos elementos passados
    var ctxA = contexto(a);
    var ctxB = contexto(b);

    // Se a é descendente de b, considera que a está na frente
    if(descendente(a, b)) return a;

    // Se b é descendente de ba, considera que b está na frente
    if(descendente(b, a)) return b;    

    // Se no mesmo contexto, compara z-índices
    if(ctxA === ctxB) {
        var zA = +css(a, 'z-index');
        var zB = +css(b, 'z-index');

        // Comparando dois z-índices definidos
        if(!isNaN(zA) && !isNaN(zB)) {
           return zB > zA ? memo[1][0] : memo[0][0];

        // Primeiro termo não definido:
        // retorna o segundo se não for NaN
        } else if(isNaN(zA)) {
            return isNaN(zB) ? memo[0][0] : memo[1][0];

        // Ambos NaN, retorna o primeiro termo
        } else {
            return memo[0][0];
        }

    // Recursão no caso de contextos diferentes
    } else {
        // Se subiu até o body, restaura o contexto anterior
        // para achamada recursiva
        ctxA = ctxA === document.body ? a : ctxA;
        ctxB = ctxB === document.body ? b : ctxB;
        return naFrente(ctxA, ctxB, memo);
    }
}
```

Porém as APIs disponíveis no browser não oferecem nenhum método para se obter o contexto de empilhamento em que um elemento está. Para implementar nossa própria função, vamos nos basear no que [a especificação diz sobre a geração dos contextos](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index):

> The root element forms the root stacking context. Other stacking contexts are generated by any positioned element (including relatively positioned elements) having a computed value of 'z-index' other than 'auto'. Stacking contexts are not necessarily related to containing blocks. In future levels of CSS, other properties may introduce stacking contexts, for example 'opacity'

Tradução livre:

> O elemento raiz forma o primeiro contexto de empihamento. Outros contextos são gerados por qualquer elemento posicionado (incluindo aqueles com posição relativa) que tenham um valor computado de 'z-index' diferente de 'auto'. Contextos de empilhamento não correspondem necessariamente a blocos contêiners. Em futuras versões do CSS, outras propriedades podem gerar contextos de empilhamento, como 'opacity'.

Portanto, para gerar um contexto de empilhamento o elemento precisa estar posicionado, e ter um `z-index` ou `opacity` (em CSS3) declarado. E como um contexto pode conter outros, vamos novamente precisar de uma função recursiva:

```
function contexto(el) {
    var ctx = el.parentElement;
    if(ctx && ctx !== document.body) {
        // Verifica se o elemento está posicionado, 
        // e se tem z-index ou opacity
        var posicionado = css(ctx, 'position') !== 'static';
        var possuiZIndex = css(ctx, 'z-index') !== 'auto';
        var naoOpaco = +css(ctx, 'opacity') < 1;

        // Se ctx for um contexto, retorna
        if(posicionado && (possuiZIndex || naoOpaco)) {
            return ctx;

        // Procura um contexto mais acima, via recursão
        } else {
            return contexto(ctx);   
        }
    // Chegamos ao elemento raiz    
    } else {
        return document.body;   
    }
}
```

Isso está bem cru ainda, e acredito que ainda precise de testes e ajustes, mas espero que tenha conseguido transmitir a idéia.

---

**TESTES do @mgibsonbr**

Meus testes dão resultados um pouco diferentes dos [originais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/889/como-comparar-elementos-html-por-z-index-real#931) nos casos em que não há z-index definido, ou em caso de empate de z-índices. Nesses casos, a ordem em que os elementos são passados faz diferença: o código retorna o primeiro elemento, `a`. Sim, isso foi uma decisão arbitrária, que não me agrada, mas são situações-limite.

- [Teste 1](http://jsfiddle.net/aN4km/)
- [Teste 2](http://jsfiddle.net/aN4km/1/)
- [Teste 3](http://jsfiddle.net/aN4km/2/)

---

**Métodos auxiliares**

(Já estão nos jsfiddles linkados acima, mas é bom registrar aqui também)

```
// Retorna true se a for descendente de b
function descendente(a, b) {
    var el = a.parentNode;
    while(el) {
      if(el === b) return true;
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

// Retorna valor computado da propriedade prop do elemento el
function css(el, prop) {
     return window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(prop);
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela tentativa, principalmente pelas referências (vou tentar implementar algo tomando o que você fez como ponto de partida). Só que o demo não parece certo, está dizendo que `dentroDeB` está na frente quando na verdade quem está na frente é `A`.

Comment: Ops, me deu um nó no final do raciocínio. Vou revisar e consertar o código, e te aviso. @mgibsonbr

Comment: Implementei algo consistente com todos meus testes até agora (usei uma estratégia diferente), mas ainda não vou postar como resposta porque precisa de mais testes (muitos *edge cases*...) [http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Fevj7/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Fevj7/3/)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Muito boa sua versão, provavelmente vou usá-la na próxima vez que precisar. Mas como sou cabeça dura, resolvi alguns dos problemas do meu código, seguindo a minha estratégia original. Eu queria manter simples, mas não tive como fugir de condicionais extras. Nos casos de empate e z-índices não definidos, decidi arbitrariamente retornar o primeiro elemento passado. Espero retomar esse assunto no futuro, quem sabe chego a uma solução melhor...

Answer (score 5):

Não tenho uma resposta absoluta, mas vou rascunhar algumas ideias sobre esse assunto.

### Pensando na Usabilidade

Com relação à figura de exemplo da pergunta, embora tecnicamente seja coerente soltar o objeto sendo arrastado no que estiver mais "perto" do usuário, isso pode causar alguma confusão para algumas pessoas.

A menos que o usuário tenha como saber que `A` está "na frente" de `B` (ou vice-versa), não faria sentido para ele que objeto sendo arrastado fosse deixado preferencialmente sobre `A` ou `B`, já que ele não tem esse conhecimento sobre *camadas*. Não seria intuitivo.

Nesse contexto, considerando que os elementos parecem estar todos em uma camada *flat*, em termos de usabilidade, a ação atual do jQuery de acionar o evento nos dois elementos faria mais sentido, desde que o conceito é "soltar onde o objeto *helper* está tocando".

### Abordagens para "Arrastar e Soltar" (*Drag & Drop*)

É importante notar que há diferentes abordagens que podem ser adotadas para o "arrastar e soltar". Exemplo:

1. O objeto pode ser solto (*drop*) num determinado alvo em potencial ao sofrer intersecção com o mesmo. Este é o conceito usado na pergunta.
2. O objeto pode ser solto num determinado alvo se aquele estiver totalmente contido dentro da área deste.
3. Outra possível abordagem seria considerar a posição do cursor do mouse como fator decisivo para definir o destino.

Considero a abordagem #1 é interessante em termos de experiência de usuário, mas tecnicamente enfrente o problema descrito na pergunta. Nos demais casos, pode-se usar o método `document.elementFromPoint()` para obter o elemento na posição do mouse (#3) ou em algum ponto do objeto sendo arrastado (#2).

**Nota:** Na abordagem #3, o objeto sendo arrastado (*helper*) não poderia ficar ob o cursor do mouse para o método `document.elementFromPoint()` funcionar. Ele teria que ser posicionado a uma certa distância do cursor.

A abordagem #3 resolveria ainda o caso dos objetos de destino estarem parcialmente  sobrepostos, pois teríamos apenas um ponto como referencial, evitando ambiguidade. Na figura abaixo, nota-se que abordagem #3 é a que mais facilitaria que o usuário pudesse soltar um elemento em `A` ou `B`.

[image: Exemplo de elementos sobrepostos]

### Usando o z-index

Fiz algumas pesquisas e testes recuperando o `z-index` via método `css` do jQuery e também com o método `getComputedStyle` (como sujerido pelo @BrunoLM). Esses métodos só retornam um valor útil se o objeto tiver o atributo `z-index` definido numericamente, caso contrário o valor retornado é `auto`.

Vamos supor que os elementos participantes dos eventos estejam sob nosso controle de forma que todos tenham o `z-indez` definido, único e estejam no mesmo nível de hierarquia do HTML, sendo filhos de um mesma ancestral. Neste caso, para descobrir o elemento mais próximo da tela basta comparar o valor do atributo `z-index` de cada alvo em potencial.

Abordagens mais complexas poderiam ser usadas, por exemplo:

- Se os elementos não tiverem `z-index` definido, mas tiverem o mesmo ancestral, pode-se verificar a posição de cada um (método `index()` do jQuery). O elemento com maior índice é o que estará mais "na frente".
- Se os elementos não tiverem `z-index`, mas seus ancestrais tiverem, isso pode ser usado para calcular uma aproximação, somando o `z-index` do "pai" com a posição do elemento filho.

Entretanto, qualquer abordagem desse tipo é uma implementação simplificada do algoritmo de empilhamento da *engine* do navegador, o que creio, devemos evitar, já que facilmente será "quebrada" por um novo caso de uso.

### Conclusão

Uma abordagem diferente para arrastar e soltar pode simplificar a implementação.

Porém, também é possível resolver a questão de forma mais simples limitando o escopo da solução a um ambiente mais controlado, por exemplo, onde todos os elementos participantes possuem um `z-index` definido e único, além de estarem estarem todos num mesmo local na árvore de elementos (*siblings*).

Comment: Não fui o *downvoter*, mas tenho algumas críticas em relação a esta resposta: 1. IMHO soltar em ambos os elementos seria a **pior** solução em termos de UX, em especial se espera-se que a ação seja exclusiva (ex.: mover); 2. Infelizmente, o `elementFromPoint` é inútil nesse caso, pois **o helper** será o elemento retornado (mesmo que se considere apenas um único ponto); 3. O algoritmo de empilhamento não é tão simples, como mostra [esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/9VgvR/); uma implementação simplificada não seria suficiente, teria de ser uma precisa.

Comment: A propósito, concordo com você que o exemplo que usei na pergunta é um caso extremo, mas mesmo uma solução mais apropriada (ex.: soltar no elemento com maior área de interseção) exige que se conheça a posição z relativa dos elementos - para se calcular corretamente essa área...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Quando ao item 1, acho que nós simplesmente discordamos então. Ao meu ver, se o *drop* é baseado em uma área de intersecção e o usuário não tem o conceito de camadas (como na imagem da pergunta), ele só vai poder se perguntar porque a objeto vai parar no item `B` e não em `A`. Fica ambíguo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Quanto ao item 2, é possível colocar o `helper` ao lado do mouse, como [neste exemplo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style) do jQuery UI (caixinha #2).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Quanto ao item 3, é verdade, por isso repetidamente e em vários pontos da resposta eu apontei que a solução para um problema complexo como esse seria limitar o escopo da solução e evitar reinventar o algoritmo de empilhamento. Vou atualizar um ponto a resposta para ficar mais coerente. Isso funcionaria no caso dos elementos estarem numa mesma árvore.

Comment: A questão da experiência do usuário no arrastar-e-soltar é complexa, acho até que merece uma pergunta à parte. Quanto aos demais comentários, concordo, e achei essa abordagem de mover o helper bastante útil. +1

Comment: De qualquer forma, já favoritei a questão para ir acompanhando as boas ideias que o pessoal tem.

Answer (score 5):

Na ausência de soluções mais simples que "reinventar a roda", segue minha tentativa de escrever uma função consistente com o algoritmo de empilhamento usado pelos *browsers*:

```js
function naFrente(a, b) {
    // Salta todos os ancestrais em comum, pois não importa seu contexto de empilamento:
    // ele afeta a e b de maneira igual
    var pa = $(a).parents(), ia = pa.length;
    var pb = $(b).parents(), ib = pb.length;
    while ( ia >= 0 && ib >= 0 && pa[--ia] == pb[--ib] ) { }

    // Aqui temos o primeiro elemento diferente nas árvores de a e b
    var ctxA = (ia >= 0 ? pa[ia] : a), za = zIndex(ctxA);
    var ctxB = (ib >= 0 ? pb[ib] : b), zb = zIndex(ctxB);

    // Em último caso, olha as posições relativas
    // (Esse valor só será usado se não tiver nenhum z-index explícito)
    var relativo = posicaoRelativa(ctxA, ctxB, a, b);

    // Acha o primeiro com zIndex definido
    // O ancestral "mais fundo" é que importa, uma vez que ele define o contexto de
    // empilhamento mais geral.
    while ( ctxA && za === undefined ) {
        ctxA = ia < 0 ? null : --ia < 0 ? a : pa[ia];
        za = zIndex(ctxA);
    }
    while ( ctxB && zb === undefined ) {
        ctxB = ib < 0 ? null : --ib < 0 ? b : pb[ib];
        zb = zIndex(ctxB);
    }

    // Compara os z-indices, ou usa o método relativo
    if ( za !== undefined ) {
        if ( zb !== undefined )
            return za > zb ? a : za < zb ? b : relativo;
        return za > 0 ? a : za < 0 ? b : relativo;
    }
    else if ( zb !== undefined )
        return zb < 0 ? a : zb > 0 ? b : relativo;
    else
        return relativo;
}

/* Adaptado do código de @bfavaretto
   Retorna um valor se o z-index for definido, undefined caso contrário.
*/   
function zIndex(ctx) {
    if ( !ctx || ctx === document.body ) return;

    // Verifica se o elemento está posicionado, 
    // e se tem z-index ou opacity
    var posicionado = css(ctx, 'position') !== 'static';
    var possuiZIndex = css(ctx, 'z-index') !== 'auto';
    var naoOpaco = +css(ctx, 'opacity') < 1;

    // Se ctx for um contexto, retorna
    //if(posicionado && (possuiZIndex || naoOpaco)) {
    if(posicionado && possuiZIndex) // Ignorando CSS3 por ora
        return +css(ctx, 'z-index');
}

/* Utilitário sugerido por @BrunoLM
   Obtém o valor de uma propriedade CSS levando em consideração a herança, sem jQuery.
*/
function css(el, prop) {
     return window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(prop);
}

/* Na ausência de z-index definido, deve comparar os elementos em pré-ordem,
   profundidade primeiro. Há edge cases ainda não tratados.
*/
function posicaoRelativa(ctxA, ctxB, a, b) {
    // Se um elemento é ancestral do outro, o descendente está na frente
    if ( $.inArray(b, $(a).parents()) >= 0 )
        return a;
    if ( $.inArray(a, $(b).parents()) >= 0 )
        return b;
    // Se dois contextos são irmãos, o declarado depois está na frente
    return ($(ctxA).index() - $(ctxB).index() > 0 ? a : b);
}
```

[Exemplo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Fevj7/8/). [Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Fevj7/9/). [Exemplo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Fevj7/10/). Estou seguro da correção do código acima **exceto** pelo `posicaoRelativa`: ainda que ele esteja consistente com todos os testes apresentados, ele foi elaborado por tentativa e erro, carecendo portanto de uma revisão que garanta conformidade às especificações.