# z-index de um elemento sem posição defenida

Tags: javascript, css

É possível saber o `z-index` de um elemento sem posição defenida usando javascript?

Por exemplo neste código:

CSS

```
#exemplo1 {
    z-index:4;
}
#exemplo2 {
    z-index:4;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="exemplo1"></div>
<div id="exemplo2"></div>
```

É possível obter o `z-index` do `exemplo1`, neste caso `4`, ainda que a `position` não esteja defenida?

O que eu testei:

```
var e1 = document.getElementById('exemplo1');
var e2 = document.getElementById('exemplo2');
console.log(e1.style.zIndex); // nada
console.log(e2.style.zIndex); // nada
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(e1).getPropertyValue("z-index")); // auto no Chrome, 4 no IE11 e FF
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(e2).getPropertyValue("z-index")); // 4
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf726/)

Comment: Se o *computed style* está retornando `auto`, é porque a engine de renderização não vai considerar o `z-index` para esse elemento (não vai mudar seu índice z, nem criar um novo contexto de empilhamento). Nesse caso, qual a utilidade de se obter o valor tal como definido no CSS?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, o curioso é que o IE11 e o FF retornam `4` mas o Chrome retorna `auto`. O que eu procuro é uma maneira uniforme/consistente para isto.

Comment: Isso é um bug que afeta todos webkit. Está documentado, mas ainda com status não confirmado: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minha única sugestão é trocar momentaneamente a posição do seu elemento para `relative`, observar o `z-index`, e depois voltar a posição ao que era antes:

```
var pos = e1.style.position;
e1.style.position = "relative";
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(e1).getPropertyValue("z-index"));
e1.style.position = pos;
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf726/1/). Como a execução de JavaScript na página principal é **síncrona**, isso não vai causar nenhum glitch visual.

Comment: Também pensei nesta solução mas não tenho a certeza que browsers diferentes leiam a ausência de position de forma consistente. Vou dar uma olhada... entretanto: `+1`

Comment: Usando só `var pos = e1.style.position;` não chega... http://jsfiddle.net/8XKXk/

Comment: @Sergio Você não entendeu, eu leio essa posição só pra reatribuí-la depois da leitura do `z-index` (pois quero que fique igual a antes), mas ela não corresponde necessariamente à posição computada. E quanto ao comportamento de browsers diferentes, eles **têm** que retornar o `z-index` correto, de acordo com [a especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). Se não o fazem, é um bug. Ver [essa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/889/como-comparar-elementos-html-por-z-index-real?rq=1).

Comment: Ok, estou a ver, para "enganar" o browser. Sim de facto esse modelo __[não deixa rasto](http://jsfiddle.net/Pd7k5/)__. Obrigado!

Comment: Já agora, se tiver alguma ideia para os IEs sem `getComputedStyle` junte aqui. Eu vou procurar também.

Comment: @Sergio Já tentou um *shim*? [Aqui por exemplo tem um](http://johnkpaul.tumblr.com/post/17380987688/shim-for-javascript). Eu testaria, mas estou sem nenhuma versão usável do IE aqui...

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada! obrigado